# C# XML linq query

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Hi I have the following XML:

```
<EPICORTLOG>
    <POS>
        <ClientId>WkStn.90.1</ClientId> 
        <Id>POS.90.20140819.251.8279</Id> 
        <StartTime>2014-08-25T05:12:34</StartTime> 
        <Store>90</Store> 
        <SysDate>2014-08-19T00:00:00</SysDate> 
        <TillNo>1</TillNo> 
        <Time>2014-08-25T05:12:34</Time> 
        <Tran>1093</Tran> 
        <WkStn>1</WkStn> 
        <WORKSTATION>
            <IsAutoLock>1</IsAutoLock> 
        </WORKSTATION>
        <TRADE>     
            <ITEM>
                <Class>102499</Class>  
                <Desc>NIKE RACER</Desc>   
                <FinalPrice>82.77</FinalPrice>   
                <Status>ACTV</Status> 
                <Style>EV0615</Style> 
                <Tag>1</Tag> 
            </ITEM>
        </TRADE>
    </POS>
</EPICORTLOG>
```

There are many POS nodes like above in the actual XML. I am trying to fetch the POS node with ID=POS.90.20140819.251.8279 and then the details of Item from that particular node. I have written the following query:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(XMLFile);    
var item = from items in xdoc.Element("EPICORTLOG").Descendants("POS")
           where items.Attribute("Id").Value == strSelectedPOSID
           select new
           {
               desc=items.Element("ITEM").Attribute("Desc")
           };
```

But it is not yielding any result for me. Here strSelectedPOSID=POS.90.20140819.251.8279. Please let me know where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`Id` and `Desc` are **not** an `Attributes`. they are `Elements` so you should use

```
var item = from items in xdoc.Descendants("POS")
           where (string)items.Element("Id") == strSelectedPOSID     
           select new
                  {
                      desc = (string)items.Element("ITEM").Element("Desc")
                  };
```

Comment: it is still giving object reference not set to an instance of an object error when i try to evaluate the expression in Quick Watch. Please help.

Comment: I have modified it like the following:var item = from items in xdoc.Element("EPICORTLOG").Descendants("POS")
                       where (string)items.Element("Id") == strSelectedPOSID
                       select new
                       {
                           desc=items.Element("TRADE").Element("ITEM").Attribute("Desc")
                       };

Answer (score 1):

I got the value at last!! Following is what i used:

```
 var item = from items in xdoc.Element("EPICORTLOG").Descendants("POS")
                   where (string)items.Element("Id") == strSelectedPOSID
                   select new
                   {
                       desc =   items.Element("TRADE").Element("ITEM").Element("Desc").Value.ToString()
                   };
```

Thanks for the inputs.